# Compiling with clang++ fails but g++ works

Tags: c++, macos

I have this toy program (with some includes commented out for debugging):

```
// #include "tutorial3/lib/func1.h"
// #include "tutorial3/lib/func2.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    // func1();
    // func2();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with

`g++ tutorial3/app/main.cpp`

it compiles and I get `Hello World` when running `a.out`.

If I compile with clang++:

`clang++ tutorial3/app/main.cpp -ferror-limit=10`

I get

```
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:106:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mbstate_t.h:51:5: error: "We don't know how to get the definition of mbstate_t without <wchar.h> on your platform."
   51 | #   error "We don't know how to get the definition of mbstate_t without <wchar.h> on your platform."
      |     ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:123:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  123 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:123:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  123 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:124:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  124 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    wstreampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:124:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  124 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    wstreampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:128:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  128 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u16streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:128:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  128 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u16streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:129:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  129 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u32streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:129:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  129 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u32streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from tutorial3/app/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:222:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:22:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocation_guard.h:15:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/construct_at.h:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/new:99:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:87:
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:148:34: error: unknown type name 'ldiv_t'
  148 | inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ldiv_t div(long __x, long __y) _NOEXCEPT {
      |                                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
11 errors generated
```

If you just type `g++` in the terminal it says `clang`, so that looks just like an alias for clang?

What is missing for `clang++`to work? I guess there are some hidden includes and linking done by `g++` that makes it compile?

I am using Mac OS Sonoma 14.1.2.

If I uninstall llvm from brew then the problem goes away. Seems like I was using llvm-clang instead of apple-clang. As suggested by @NathanOliver.

Comment: looks like your homebrew installation of clang++ is not configured correctly.  Are you trying to use the built in apple clang or llvm-clang that you installed yourself?  By default `g++` is an alias for `apple-clang` on MacOS

Comment: How did you install Clang? From the error messages, I guess it is through Homebrew. Maybe there is a conflict with the Apple Clang that comes from Xcode or the Apple "Command line tools".

Comment: Yes, removing llvm solves the issue!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.