# Homebrew Clang C++ compilation fails

Tags: c++, macos, clang, homebrew, llvm

I am having a similar issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728163/compiling-with-clang-fails-but-g-works), but I am opening a new question -- while the symptom is the same, my goal is different. In that question, removing `llvm-clang` solved their issue -- I assume the default Apple `clang` fit their needs. In my situation, I am intentionally trying to install and use Homebrew `clang`, not Apple's default. I am on macOS Sonoma and want the upgraded compiler to access C++23 language features (such as `std::print`).

My default version of Apple Clang (by running `clang --version`) is 14:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I installed the latest version of llvm using `brew install llvm`, which installs version 17. Following the tips here:

- [How to switch from Apple to Homebrew-installed clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225495/how-to-switch-from-apple-to-homebrew-installed-clang)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/moirt4/apple_clang_vs_clang/

I modified my ~./zshrc to add the updated `llvm` to PATH, as well as changing the `CC` and `CXX` variables to expose the new compiler to CMake:

```
PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
export CC=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/clang
export CXX=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/clang++
```

With these changes in effect, I can verify that `clang` points to the right version now:

```
$ clang --version
Homebrew clang version 17.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin
```

Now, to compile a simple program:

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main() { std::cout << "Hello world" << '\n'; }
```

```
$ clang -std=c++23 main.cpp -ferror-limit=10
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:106:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mbstate_t.h:51:5: error: "We don't know how to get the definition of mbstate_t without <wchar.h> on your platform."
   51 | #   error "We don't know how to get the definition of mbstate_t without <wchar.h> on your platform."
      |     ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:123:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  123 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:123:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  123 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:124:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  124 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    wstreampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:124:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  124 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    wstreampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:126:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  126 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u8streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:126:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  126 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u8streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:128:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  128 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u16streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:128:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  128 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u16streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
In file included from main.cpp:52:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ios/fpos.h:14:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:129:14: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
  129 | typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u32streampos;
      |              ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/__std_mbstate_t.h:25:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
   25 | using ::mbstate_t _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      | ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
11 errors generated.
```

The test program isn't using any C++23 features, so this seems like a more fundamental config issue with `llvm-clang` but I may be wrong. Does anybody have suggestions?